# Coordinating the execution of a single periodic task between servers in a cluster

Tags: cluster-computing, distribution, high-availability, task-queue

(I shall try to keep this question as short as possible while clearly describing the situation. Please comment if anything is missing.)

**The situation**

- I'm running a cluster with three servers in the same datacenter
- To ease deployment, each server runs exactly the same application code

**The objective**

- To run a single task (call it *Task X*) every minute by a single server.

**Under these conditions**

- The cluster remains distributed and highly available
- Each server keeps running the same application code. In other words there is no such thing as "deploy code A to a *master server* and deploy code B to all *secondary servers*.

The reason I do not wish to distinguish between the kind of server is to maintain high availability (avoid problems when a so called master goes down), redundancy (distribute load), and to avoid creating a complex deployment procedure where I need to deploy different applications to different kinds of servers.

Why is this so difficult? If I were to add code that would execute this task every 5 minutes, then each server would execute it because each server runs the same application code. As such they need to be able to coordinate which server is going to run the same during each tick.

I am able to use distributed messaging mechanisms such as `Apache Kafka` or `Redis`. If using such mechanism to coordinate such task, how would such "algorithm" work?

I posed this question to someone else, his reply was to use a task queue. However, this does not seem to solve the issue, because the question remains: which server is going to add the task to the task queue? If all servers would add the task to the queue then it would result in duplicate entries. Moreover, which server is going to execute the next task in the queue? All this needs to be decided through coordination within the cluster, without distinguishing between different kinds of servers.

Comment: @Charles, how is this not about coordination?

Comment: Coordination as a general thing is very, very vague, and would make a bad tag.  The existing tags classify your question pretty well.

Comment: Thanks for adding this, it beautifully describes the problem I was about to write up :)

Comment: @Steven, that's great. In what language are you working?

Comment: @Tom, Python/Django environment, but pretty much the same problem. I have several machines, I want one of them to do Task x, but not all of them, but I don't want a master machine. I want one machine to be able to drop out of existence without any ill effect (save load/redundancy etc.)

Comment: @Steven, alright that's exactly what I needed. The distributed lock worked for me (See answer, with MongoDB instead of Redis). The most important thing to do is to make sure that the database can unlock the task if the server running the task goes offline, by setting a timeout (or TTL).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you are looking for a distributed lock. Redis does this wonderfully with `setnx`. If you combine it with `expire` then you can create global locks that are released every N Seconds.

`setnx` will only write the value and return true if the key does not already exist. Redis operations are atomic so only the first server to call `setnx` after the key expires will get the go ahead to run the task.

Here is an example in ruby:

```
# Attempt to get the lock for 'Task X' by setting the current server's hostname
if redis.setnx("lock:task:x", `hostname`.chomp)
  # Got the lock, now I set it to expire after 5 minutes
  redis.expire("lock:task:x", 60 * 5)
  # This server has the go ahead to execute the task
  execute_task_x
else
  # Failed to get the lock. Another server is doing the work this time around
end
```

With this you are still reliant on calling one server `Redis Master` unless you take advantage of `redis-sentinel`. Take a look at [the redis-sentinel docs](http://redis.io/topics/sentinel) for information on how to configure automatic fallover.

Comment: Interesting, I had not thought that a database can help me out here. I did mention Redis, but more for it's pubsub. Do you know if the same is possible with MongoDB? DB wise I prefer it over Redis.

Comment: I believe you can although I have not tried it personally. You will have to set an unique index for a key and an expiry prior. `db.jobs.ensureIndex( { "job_x": 1 }, { expireAfterSeconds: 300 } )`

Comment: I forgot to add 'unique: true'. The mongo `ensure index` call should look something like this: `db.jobs.ensureIndex( { "job_x": 1 }, { unique: true, expireAfterSeconds: 300 } )`. Keep in mind that Redis only uses 1MB of memory when empty and has a great many uses other than the one above.

Comment: Thanks, I will give this a try and report back. Note that it requires MongoDB 2.2+ (http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/expire-data/).

Comment: +50 It works, but the value has to be of type `Date`. Therefore another index is required with the unique field, because a Date is never unique.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [JGroups](http://www.jgroups.org/) to achieve this. Sample implementation can be found [here](http://speakingjava.blogspot.in/2014/10/how-to-execute-singleton-task-in-cluster.html)